# Got an error message. "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Tags: discussion

Please explain, in simple terms, how to get the correct format of stuff in this window. Did the code fence. Fail. I pasted my code in the window. Included the 3 back ticks before and after. Included a few comments following the code. This should be a simple process. Now what?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216464/how-to-insert-code-properly-on-stack-overflow. You can also look here

Comment: The message told you exactly what was wrong. You need to give sufficient background. If most of your post is just code, you haven't given enough context.

Comment: Write your issue first then post the code surrounded by 3 backticks. Look at the info at top of the edit page, which explains everything.

Comment: Are you explaining your question/problem/code with adequate amounts of non-code explanatory text?

Comment: Some of these questions might help you determine what the root cause for the error on your post is: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=It+looks+like+your+post+is+mostly+code%3B+please+add+some+more+detail+is%3Aq

Comment: maybe helpful https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: This, and your other off topic question, strongly suggests you need to read the [Help]. If you only had read that [tour] when it was offered to you ...

Answer (score 3):

Well it may be obvious but why not simply follow the suggestion and write more non-code text?

- What does your code do?
- What should it do instead?
- What error are you getting?
- What debugging have you done? Why was that unrevealing?

And perhaps less obviously, maybe you could also write less code. Given that the ratio of code to non-code is the issue, that's the other way to fix that.

- Is every line of the code you're trying to post absolutely crucial in order to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: In response to  this response: Well it may be obvious but why not simply follow the suggestion and write more non-code text?
1) I tried. 14 lines for 74 lines of code. Still fail.
What does your code do?
What should it do instead?
What error are you getting?
What debugging have you done? Why was that unrevealing?
And perhaps less obviously, maybe you could also write less code. Given that the ratio of code to non-code is the issue, that's the other way to fix that.

Is every line of the code you're trying to post absolutely crucial in order to demonstrate the issue?